# How to define multiple friend assemblies when generating AssemblyInfo from .csproj file?

Tags: c#, friend, assemblyinfo, internalsvisibleto

I would like to define several friend assemblies. 
It is easy to do so when editing the `AssemblyInfo` file manually:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1a")]
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1b")]
```

or

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Friend2a"), 
      InternalsVisibleTo("Friend2b")]
```

However my `AssemblyInfo` file is generated by an *MSBuild task* from the `.csproj` file. In this case, I can add one `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute, but not several.

```
<AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS" OutputFile="$(AssemblyInfoFile)"  AssemblyVersion="$(Version)" InternalsVisibleTo = "Friend1a"/>
```

How can I define multiple friend assemblies in my `.csproj` file?

Answer (score 10):

You can add multiple friendly assemblies in `.csproj` files via `AssemblyAttribute`. Place the following code inside a root tag:

`<ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
      <_Parameter1>Friend1</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
      <_Parameter1>Friend2</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 1):

Just add them in another file. 'ExtraAssemblyInfo.cs'. There is nothing special code-wise about the AssemblyInfo file it's just a long standing convention.